# Django “python-social-auth”: HTTP 403 Client Error with github

Tags: django, github, python-social-auth

I've followed closely [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html) tutorial which is great.
Everything worked fine until today, where when I log with github I get this error:

```
HTTPError at /oauth/complete/github/
403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
```

What am I missing / what could I have changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently developping a Website with social networks login.
Everything works fine (google, facebook and twitter) but **not github**: after some attempts, I'm getting now a 403.

The problem in Django is that 403 errors dont show the HTML content that come with the error!

I had to run in Debug mode and add a breakpoint in the file

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py
```

line 940 / where there's the code `raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)`

Inspecting the variable `self.content.decode("utf-8")` showed me that I've been restricted (for no logical reason - what's more strange is that the same code, on my same PC but under Windows, works like a charm).

I'm hoping the technical team at github will explain what went wrong...